# Expo Go keeps stopping. How do I see error details for react native applications?

Tags: react-native, debugging, expo

I have a very simple React Native app that I'm trying to run on Android via Expo Go.

I run expo with `npx expo start`. Whether I open the app on a physical Android device (Samsung S22) or an andoir emulator, Expo Go fails to launch the app, reporting "Expo Go keeps stopping".

The terminal window doesn't provide any detail on why the app failed:

```
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
› Opening on Android...
› Opening exp://192.168.1.126:19000 on Pixel_5_API_31
› Press ? │ show all commands
Android Bundling complete 2627ms
```

On the physical android device everything closes too quickly to glean any insights.

On the emulator, I do (briefly) see some very useful information behind the diaglog. If I'm quick taking a screen shot, I can capture this:

[image: Expo Go keeps stopping screenshot]

This particular error looks like it's caused by a problematic style. However, I can't see the full error message and this isn't a very reliable / scalable way of debugging.

How / where can I get full error details for problems when developing react native applications?

Comment: Well, it says right there, "Unknown valu: 20pt", there is no pt, or px, or em in react native, it's [unitless and the values represents density-independent pixels](https://reactnative.dev/docs/height-and-width#fixed-dimensions). You can just remove the pt and give the 20 as a number. If you didn't give the 20pt value, I'm afraid there's no super easy way to find it. If it comes from your codebase, you can search for it, but if a library causes this issue you may have to remove / add the usage of libraries from the component you're getting the error to see which one causes.

Comment: Thanks Urgur, I get that. That wasn't my question though. When this happens again I can try to capture the screen at the moment when some debug information flashes up and hopefully the key details aren't obscured by the dialog that shows just before the app shuts down... that also only works on the emulator (on actual devices that screen either doesn't show or shows too quick for the naked eye). I'm after a more reliable way of capturing the error message.... the full error message (regardless of whether the app is running on an emulator or a physical device).

Comment: Oh, sorry. you can use [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) to get the crash logs in android. `adb logcat *:E` for example.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @UgurEren - I found some good [https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat](info on LogCat here) for those using Android Studio (like me). 

Also, I was just prompted to update to a newer version of Expo Go on my emulator and now the Debug Log shows correctly giving me time to read it, without Expo Go shutting down immediately... so I think that must have been a problem with the version of Expo Go I was running.